# Grouping observations by cutoff time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of cutoff times `list = [16:30:00.100, 16:30:00.200, 16:30:00.350, 16:30:00.450]`.

And my observations are as follows:

```
16:30:00.095    A
16:30:00.097    B
16:30:00.122    C
16:30:00.255    D
16:30:00.322    E
16:30:00.420    F
16:30:00.569    G
```

What I want to achieve here is to group my observations based on the cutoff times (specifically, I want to see which one of my cutoff times are able to capture the observations - i.e. first cutoff time is fast enough to catch C, but too slow for A/B). Desired output should look something like this:

```
cutoff          observations captured

16:30:00.100    C
16:30:00.200    D    E
16:30:00.350    F
16:30:00.450    G
not possible    A    B
```

I have tried using `pd.cut`, but it doesn't allow for time sensitivity up to the milliseconds, or at least not that I am aware of. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think idea with [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) working nice, also time data are converted to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), replace non matching values by `fillna` and last aggregate `join`:

```
print (df)
           time col
0  16:30:00.095   A
1  16:30:00.097   B
2  16:30:00.122   C
3  16:30:00.255   D
4  16:30:00.322   E
5  16:30:00.420   F
6  16:30:00.569   G
```

---

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str))

L = ['16:30:00.100', '16:30:00.200', '16:30:00.350', '16:30:00.450']
v = pd.to_timedelta(L + [pd.Timedelta.max])
df['b'] = pd.cut(df['time'], bins=v, labels = L)
df['b'] = df['b'].cat.add_categories(['not possible'])
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna('not possible')
print (df)
             time col             b
0 16:30:00.095000   A  not possible
1 16:30:00.097000   B  not possible
2 16:30:00.122000   C  16:30:00.100
3 16:30:00.255000   D  16:30:00.200
4 16:30:00.322000   E  16:30:00.200
5 16:30:00.420000   F  16:30:00.350
6 16:30:00.569000   G  16:30:00.450
```

---

```
df2 = df.groupby('b')['col'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
print (df2)
              b   col
0  16:30:00.100     C
1  16:30:00.200  D, E
2  16:30:00.350     F
3  16:30:00.450     G
4  not possible  A, B
```

Comment: thanks for the help! one further thing though - if L contains duplicates, is it possible for me to append ````col```` to the last instance of duplicates, instead of using ````duplicates='drop'````?

Comment: Also, is it possible to append a new element in ````col```` on the next cell, instead of it being separated by ````, ````

Comment: @AdrianY - Unfortunately `L` cannon contains duplicates for `pd.cut`, for next cell do you think omit `df2 = df.groupby('b')['col'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()` ?